# How to prove an inequality involving maximization, difference and absolute value operators?

Tags: real-analysis

How can we prove the following.

$|\max f(x)-\max g(x)| \le \max |f(x)-g(x)|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ attain their maximums at $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively (assuming that they exist), i.e,
$$\max f(x)=f(\alpha)\\
\max g(x)=g(\beta)$$
WLOG let $f(\alpha)\geq g(\beta)$. Then,
\begin{align}
|f(\alpha)-g(\alpha)|&\geq|f(\alpha)-g(\beta)|\hspace{1cm}(\because g(\alpha)\leq g(\beta))\\
\text{and}\\
\max|f(x)-g(x)|&\geq|f(\alpha)-g(\alpha)|\\
\implies \max|f(x)-g(x)|&\geq|f(\alpha)-g(\beta)|
\end{align}
$$\hspace{4cm}\square$$